# Agendar tarefa para executar no servidor do Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, cron, scheduler, agendamento

Preciso criar um executor de tarefas onde o mesmo vai chamar um método de tempos em tempos.

Eu vi um exemplo e ficou assim minha implementação:

```
public class Agendador {
  // Scheduler
  private final ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

  final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      EncomendaController controller = new EncomendaController();
      controller.pesquisar();
    }
  };
  // Beeper Handler
  final ScheduledFuture<?> b = s.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Como posso fazer para que o **Wildfly** execute o agendamento e a execução dessa tarefa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exemplo para o método `funcaoAgendada()` ser invocado a cada um segundo:

```
@Singleton
public class Agendador {
    @Schedule(second = "*/1", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
    public void funcaoAgendada() {
        System.out.println("Função Agendada em execução!");
    }
}
```

Seu agendador também pode ser ter escopo `@Stateless` ou `@Stateful` depende da necessidade.

Comment: Qual a diferença deles?

Comment: Stateless não mantém o estado do objeto, Singleton como o stateless com apenas 1 instância, Stateful mantém todo o estado do objeto. Aconselho ler sobre Padrões de Projeto (Design Patterns) e Estado de Sessão do EJB pois a pergunta é complexa.

Comment: Entendi, ele está chamando o método mas ele está dando nullpointer no método não sei pq :(

Comment: Só pelo erro fica difícil saber, qualquer coisa abre uma nova pergunta...

Comment: Já vi o que era, obrigado :)